# Regex fails with whitespace

Tags: php, html, css, regex

> $match = array('~(?:face\=[\'"]?(\w+)[\'"]?)~i', '~~i');
>   $replace = array('font-family:$1;', '<span style="$1">');

I want to replace the old <font> element which has a "face" attribute with a new <span> element with "style" attribute but the regex always fail when the font name in the "face" attribute contains whitespace, e.g : Courier New. How can I modify the regex to solve this problem?

Comment: It's generally not a great idea to parse HTML with a regex.

Comment: But my HTML is just simple so I don't need to use DOM to parse it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `\w+` with `.+` to include all characters instead of just 'word' characters.  Or all characters *except* `'` like this: `[^\']+`

Updated version:

```
$match = array('~(?:face\=[\'"]?([^\']+)[\'"]?)~i', '~~i');
$replace = array('font-family:$1;', '<span style="$1">');
```